# Fail fast under load (by setting request timeout)

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-http

We have a Play 2.6.x application that is being stress tested at the moment (using Gatling). Under heavy load we don't mind requests failing if the application responds quickly - i.e. within 100ms. The action does a bit of CPU work and some IO - all asynchronously (but disabling IO with stubs yields the same results)

What we noticed is that setting `akka.http.server.request-timeout=100ms` makes no difference when the application is under load - the 99th percentile still blows up to several seconds, with some requests taking longer than 60s (which is the point at which Gatling gives up with `Request Timeout` exception).

To somewhat reproduce that in a more isolated environment, I've used https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-starter-example and added actions which put different threads to sleep in different ways (switching between threadpools and methods). Here's the actions I've defined:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise, blocking}

@Singleton
class AsyncController @Inject()(
                                 cc: ControllerComponents,
                                 actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                                 configuration: Configuration
                               )(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def message_delay = Action.async {
    getFutureMessage(1.second).map { msg => Ok("hello") }
  }

  def message_delay_bg = Action.async {
    getFutureMessage(1.second)(ExecutionContext.global).map { msg => Ok("hello") }
  }


  def message_sleep = Action.async {
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      Ok("hello")
    }
  }

  def message_sleep_bg = Action.async {
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      Ok("hello")
    }(ExecutionContext.global)
  }

  def message_block_sleep = Action.async {
    Future {
      blocking {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        Ok("hello")
      }
    }
  }

  def message_block_sleep_bg = Action.async {
    Future {
      blocking {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        Ok("hello")
      }
    }(ExecutionContext.global)
  }


  private def getFutureMessage(delayTime: FiniteDuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[String] = {
    val promise: Promise[String] = Promise[String]()
    actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delayTime) {
      promise.success("Hi!")
    }(ec) // run scheduled tasks using the actor system's dispatcher
    promise.future
  }

}
```

After doing some load testing here are the results I've got:

[image: Gatling results]

If you ignore the connection timeouts and "failed to open socket" errors (probably limitations on my laptop), there's still a hefty amount of requests that overran 60 seconds (along with returned 503s).

**Finally, the questions**

1. Is it possible to implement this failfast scenario?
2. Is it expected to be this sensitive to heavy load?
3. If something is wrong with my setup, how do I fix it.

Comment: Have not got it what are you testing if you have Thread.Sleep(1000) ? It's not async operation - so no other operation can use this Thread and also you'll exceed thread pool very fast.

Comment: I did a similar experiment with `Thread.sleep(150)` instead, to similar results to simulate a shorter more realistic delay. The reason I'm using thread sleep is to simulate potentially blocking or just CPU heavy operations that can occur in our endpoints (they occur in a separate threadpool) and I want to confirm that in this case Akka-http won't be able to terminate that request early under load